# How to print a a certain value of a variable on a text string with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering how I could print a certain value of a variable on a text string.
Here is my code.

```
import requests
import time
import json

urls = ["https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/doodles-official/stats",
    "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/boredapeyachtclub/stats",
        "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/mutant-ape-yacht-club/stats",
        "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/bored-ape-kennel-club/stats"]

for url in urls:

    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data= json.loads(response.text)
    data= (json_data["stats"]["floor_price"])

print("this is the floor price of {} of doodles!".format(data))
print("this is the floor price of {} of Bored Apes!".format(data))
```

As you can see in the code I am using the opensea API to extract the value of floor price from a json file of the different NFT collections listed on the urls.
The variable if you print the variable data you will get the different prices as follow:
[image: image of output]
The question is how can I take a specific value of that output, lets say 7.44 for example, and print in the following text

```
print("this is the floor price of {} of doodles!".format(data))
```

and then use the second value, 85, and print another text such as:

```
print("this is the floor price of {} of Bored Apes!".format(data))
```

How can I generate this output?
Thanks everyone!

I tried using data[0] or data[1], but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion is to make another list, and add all the data to that list. For example, you can say `data_list = []` to define a new list.

Then, in your for loop, add `data_list.append(data)`, which adds the data to your list. Now, you can use `data_list[0]` and `data_list[1]` to access the different data.

The full code would look something like this:

```py
import requests
import time
import json

urls = ["https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/doodles-official/stats",
    "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/boredapeyachtclub/stats",
        "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/mutant-ape-yacht-club/stats",
        "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/bored-ape-kennel-club/stats"]

data_list = []
for url in urls:

    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data= json.loads(response.text)
    data= (json_data["stats"]["floor_price"])

    data_list.append(data)

print("this is the floor price of {} of doodles!".format(data_list[0]))
print("this is the floor price of {} of Bored Apes!".format(data_list[1]))
```

The reason you cannot use `data[0]` and `data[1]` is because the variable data is rewritten each time the for loop runs again, and nothing is added.